# terraform `map` alternative when duplicated keys should raise error

Tags: dictionary, terraform, duplicates, key

### Given that:

As described also in https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/28727, if we have duplicated keys in a map, we get NO error:

> quoting below from github issue

```
locals {
  local_dbs = {
    db1 = { a = "1a" }
    db1 = { a = "2a" }    // notice the key here is the same as the previous (e.g. a mistake)
    db3 = { a = "3a" }
  }
}

output locals_map_out {
  value = local.local_dbs
}
```

The above produces these outputs

```
Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

locals_map_out = {
  "db1" = {
    "a" = "2a"
  }
  "db3" = {
    "a" = "3a"
  }
}
```

Notice the loss of the 1st db1 map entry. There was no error and no warning. It just silently replaced the 1st map entry with the 2nd.

> end of quoting from github issue

### My question is:

##### What would be a good (similar looking, elegant, few lines of code) alternative to using the `map` that would raise an error case duplicated "keys"?

Ex. A list of maps + validation code?

```
locals {
  local_dbs = [
    {db1 = { a = "1a" }},
    {db1 = { a = "2a" }},   // notice the key here is the same as the previous (e.g. a mistake)
    {db3 = { a = "3a" }},
  ]

  // code that raises error?
}

output locals_map_out {
  value = local.local_dbs
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no custom errors or exceptions in TF, but one way to check for duplicates, would be to get a list of unique keys, and then try to access the last element. If all keys are really unique, the operation will succeed. If not, it errors out:

```
locals {
  local_dbs = [
    {db1 = { a = "1a" }},
    {db1 = { a = "2a" }},   // notice the key here is the same as the previous (e.g. a mistake)
    {db3 = { a = "3a" }},
  ]

  check_duplicatates = distinct([for v in local.local_dbs: keys(v)])[length(local.local_dbs)-1]
}
```

**update**

With `output` as @MarkoE suggested:

```
output "check_duplicatates" {
  value = local.local_dbs
  #sensitive = true
  precondition {
    condition     = length(distinct([for v in local.local_dbs: keys(v)])) == length(local.local_dbs)
    error_message = "Keys in local.local_dbs are NOT unique."
  }
}
```

Comment: If this is needed in the output, maybe it could be used with `precondition` as well.

Comment: @MarkoE Good idea. Thanks. I added this to the answer.